# Ordinals and fusibles - why write $2\omega^2$?

Tags: ordinals

I was reading through [this pdf](http://www.mathpuzzle.com/fusible.pdf) on fusibles, and on page 16, ordinals are introduced.

I understand the concept, but my issue is with the notation. Rather than $2\omega^2$, should the author not have written $\omega^22$? From what I've understood by reading the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number), $2\omega^2$ is the same as $\omega^2$, as there is an isometry between their elements. On the other hand, $\omega^22$ is bigger.

Comment: $2\omega^2$ is not the same as $\omega^2$. It's $\omega^2+\omega^2$, which is the smallest ordinal that's bigger than all $\omega^2+n\omega$, just like $\omega^2$ is the smallest ordinal that's bigger than all $n\omega$.

Comment: Mind, $1+\omega=\omega$ whereas $\omega+1$ is the smallest ordinal that's bigger than $\omega$. Also $\omega+\omega^2=\omega^2\neq\omega^2+\omega$.

Comment: @Heimdall so $2\omega=\omega$, but $2\omega^2\neq\omega^2$?

Comment: No. $2\omega=\omega+\omega$, which is the smallest ordinal bigger than $\omega+n$ for all $n\in N$. $\omega+1$ is the smallest ordinal bigger than $\omega$. $\omega+4$ is the smallest ordinal bigger than $\omega+3$. Just like $\omega$ is the smallest ordinal bigger than any finite ordinal and 4 is the smallest ordinal bigger than 3.

Comment: @Heimdall so what does the Wiki article mean when it writes $2\omega=\omega$? I don't understand. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_arithmetic#Multiplication

Comment: Ah! I've read the Wikipedia page. The author of your pdf and the Wikipedia use different convention. When your pdf mentions $2\omega$, he refers to what the Wikipedia article writes as $\omega\cdot2$. I always used the same convention as your pdf, not considering that as a multiplication but as a notation, like with complex numbers where + in a+bi is not an addition. Wikipedia article, on the other hand, marks the number $\omega+\omega$ as $\omega\cdot2$ because it matches with the definition of ordinal multiplication whereas $2\omega$ doesn't.

Comment: @Heimdall ok, so just to clarify - how would you write what Wikipedia denotes $2\cdot\omega$?

Comment: I guess the same. I haven't thought of multiplying ordinals before. I would probably use a dot and I will possibly in the future avoid writing $2\omega$ for either $\omega+\omega$ or $2\cdot\omega$ to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To address the title of your question: it really just depends on how you choose to define ordinal multiplication.

In the majority of the literature (certainly that which I've seen), ordinal multiplication is defined as a lexicographic ordering on the Cartesian product of two ordinals where the *least* significant position is compared first.

Under this definition, it makes sense to denote the ordinal $\sup\{\omega + n \mid n \in \omega\}$ as $\omega\cdot2$ since we would order the set $\omega \times 2$ as:

$$(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (3, 0),\ \dots,  (0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1)\ \dots$$

Writing $2\cdot\omega$ would really imply the ordering of $\omega \times 2$ to be:

$$(0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (0, 3), (1, 3),\ \dots$$

which just has order-type $\omega$.

[MathWorld's article on ordinal multiplication](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/OrdinalMultiplication.html) notes a couple of sources that use a lexicographic ordering where the $most$ significant position is compared first, i.e.:

$$(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3),\ \dots,  (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3),\ \dots$$

So using this definition of lexicographic order, the ordinal $\sup\{\omega + n \mid n \in \omega\}$ would sensibly be denoted $2\cdot\omega$. Perhaps  this is what the author of the presentation had in mind.